# python web scraping,web parser

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, request, html-parsing

I just start learning python, and I have problem with scraping.
Code work correctly, but when I scrape , but get only empty list [].
what I do wrong?
I can't find same problem , Thanks for your time!

```
`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

headers = {
"accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"

}

url = "https://www.worldometers.info/geography/alphabetical-list-of-countries/"
session = requests.session()


try:
    req = session.get(url, headers=headers)
    if req.status_code == 200:
        soup =  bs4(req.content, "html.parser")
        divs = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"style" : "font-weight"})
        name = soup.find_all()
        print(divs)
except Exception:
    print("ERORR IN URL ADRESS")`
```

Comment: It is because there is no element that satisfies the attributes you passed. What are the elements that you want to extract?

Comment: I want to print all countries.

Comment: do some checking and make sure what you want isn't generated by JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the table with class `table-condensed` and find the data you need. Please check the below code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
"accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"

}

url = "https://www.worldometers.info/geography/alphabetical-list-of-countries/"
session = requests.session()


try:
    req = session.get(url, headers=headers)
    if req.status_code == 200:
        soup =  BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
        countries = soup.find("table", {"class": "table-condensed"}).find("tbody").findAll("tr")
        for country in countries:
            print(country.findAll("td")[1].text)
            
except Exception:
    print("ERORR IN URL ADRESS")
```

Comment: Please approve the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Sorry for so stupid question, but how i can approve ?

Comment: There is a tick icon on the left side of the answer